# Google SSO on Android with Adobe AIR

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, single-sign-on

I am developing a flex/air mobile application. Can anyone point me to .ane (native extension) that provides google sso/login, or any other instructions how to authenticate android user with google login? All I need is email, first name, last name

thank you

Comment: StackOverflow does it using, in essence, a browser pop-up.  I wonder if you could set something up from within an AIR app using StageWebView or the HTML component?  Have you read the docs?  Have you tried something?  What makes you think an ANE is needed?

Comment: surely I can do it through webview and targeting oauth service that way, however I would rather use AccountManager while user may already been logged with his device, so he does not need to relogin just for my app

Comment: That makes a lot of since; a Native Extension is probably the way to go. You should specify in your question text that you are creating a mobile question.  Despite the fact that you tagged this w/ Android and had Android in the subject line; I completely missed that point.